# How to deal with duplicates in google sheets script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

So in the project I want to do I have a google sheet with timestamps and names next to those timestamps in the spreadsheet. I am having trouble accounting for duplicates and giving the name multiple timestamps in another google sheet.

```
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){//for loop 1

if(currentCell.isBlank()){//current cell is blank
  daySheet.getRange(i+10, 2).setValue(fullName);//set name to first cell
  daySheet.getRange(i+10,3).setValue(pI);
  daySheet.getRange(i+10,day+3).setValue(1);    

}else if(counter > 1 ){//the index of the duplicate in the sheet month
      //if counter is > 1 then write duplicates
      for(var t = 1; t <= sheetLength ; t++){//loop through sign in sheet
          //current index i
          if(signInLN == signInSheet.getRange(t+1,3).getValue()){
          //if there is a match
            daySheet.getRange(t+10,day+3).setValue(1);
            //day is equal to the day I spliced from the timestamp

            //at this point I am confused on how to get the second date that has the same
            //name and add to the row with the original name.
            //when i splice the timestamp based on the row of index i, with duplicates I get 
            //the day number from the first instance where the name is read


          }
      }
}//for loop 1
```

How can I get this to work with duplicates so I can account for the dates but make sure that if there are
any duplicates they will be added to the row of the original name

```
Google Sheet EX:
12/10/2020   test1
12/11/202    test2
12/15/2020   test1
```

Should be something like this:

```
name       10   11   12   13   14   15   16
test1       1                        1
test2            1
```

//the one is to identify that the date is when the user signed in on the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Spreadsheet:

[image]

---

Code snippet done with **Apps Script**, adapt it to your needs.

use `Logger.log()` in case you don't understand parts of code

It is done mainly with **functional JavaScript**

```js
function main(){
  var inputRange = "A2:B";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0]

  var input = sheet.getRange(inputRange).getValues(); //Read data into array

  var minDate, maxDate;
  var presentDates = input.map(function(row) {return row[0];}); //Turns input into an array of only the element 0 (the date)
  minDate = presentDates.reduce(function(a,b) { return a<b?a:b}); //For each value, if its the smallest: keep; otherwise: skip;
  maxDate = presentDates.reduce(function(a,b) { return a>b?a:b}); //Same as above, but largest.

  var dates = [];
  for (var currentDate = minDate; currentDate <= maxDate; currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1)) {
    dates.push(getFormattedDate(currentDate)); //Insert each unique date from minDate to maxDate (to leave no gaps)
  }

  var uniqueNames = input.map(function(row) {return row[1];}) //Turns input into an array of only the element at 1 (the names)
                         .filter(function (value, index, self) {return self.indexOf(value) === index;}); //Removes duplicates from the array (Remove the element if the first appearence of it on the array is not the current element's index)

  var output = {}; //Temporary dictionary for easier counting later on.
  for (var i=0; i< dates.length; i++) {
    var dateKey = dates[i];
    for (var userIndex = 0; userIndex <= uniqueNames.length; userIndex++) {
      var mapKey = uniqueNames[userIndex]+dateKey; //Match each name with each date
      input.map(function(row) {return row[1]+getFormattedDate(row[0])}) //Translate input into name + date (for easier filtering)
      .filter(function (row) {return row === mapKey}) //Grab all instances where the same date as dateKey is present for the current name
      .forEach(function(row){output[mapKey] = (output[mapKey]||0) + 1;}); //Count them.
    }
  }

  var toInsert = []; //Array that will be outputted into sheets
  var firstLine  = ['names X Dates'].concat(dates); //Initialize with header (first element is hard-coded)
  toInsert.push(firstLine); //Insert header line into output.


  uniqueNames.forEach(function(name) {
    var newLine = [name];
    for (var i=0; i< dates.length; i++) { //For each name + date combination, insert the value from the output dictionary.
      var currentDate = dates[i];
      newLine.push(output[name+currentDate]||0);
    }
    toInsert.push(newLine); //Insert into the output.
  });

  sheet.getRange(1, 5, toInsert.length, toInsert[0].length).setValues(toInsert); //Write the output to the sheet
}

// Returns a date in the format MM/dd/YYYY
function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
  month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;

  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;

  return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}
```

---

Run script results:
[image]

Comment: Where was the variable currentDate instantiated as a new Date()? This generates the error that it cannot find the function getFullYear and getMonth in object .

Comment: @Gabriel, `currentDate` is declared and used in loops, but you always can use shortcut **Ctrl+F** to search stuff. If you want to get the same result as I provided, just fill column **A** with dates(*MM/dd/YYYY*) and **B** with names, then copy paste the source into scripts, and run it. You will get the same result. When you saw that it works, start adapting the code into your project.